# Autocomplete material UI component with formik is loading with errors and warnings

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik-material-ui

I have written a sample code for Autocomplete component from Material UI in next JS with formik. But I see some errors and warnings at the load. I have tried several solutions from the internet, but nothing seems to work! Could someone help me understand what the issue is and how to get that resolved? I have shared the code in the link for your reference. https://github.com/SamplesForMurthy/formiksample.

> Error: useAutocomplete.js:141 Material-UI: The `getOptionLabel` method
> of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for "".

and

> Warning: useAutocomplete.js:249 Material-UI: The value provided to
> Autocomplete is invalid. None of the options match with `""`. You can
> use the `getOptionSelected` prop to customize the equality test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you pass the empty string as a value , AutoComplete will try to compare the selected value with the list of options and checks whether there is any option which matches with your selected value .

Pass the initial value as null instead of empty string.

```
const initialValues = {
  selectedValue: null,
};
```

Comment: Really thank you. this works. But what happened when this was made null and why that error with ""? I would really appreciate any link to help me understand better.

Comment: when you pass the empty string as a value , AutoComplete will try to compare the selected value with the list of options and checks whether there is any option which matches with your selected value . I think its more of internal working of the `AutoComplete` component . I suggest you need to take a look their autocomplete source code  - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js